# Basic clarification about LIMU REPS Transport

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I just want to clarify some basic stuff about TR and transport.
Imagine I have 4 systems : DEV -> INT -> QA -> PROD.

I have two different changes locked through 2 different workbench TRs (A and B) but on the same object. This is a modification of a preexisting report so the type of the transport entry is LIMU and the object type is REPS.

First, on dev system, the first change is made and locked in the first TR (A) then transported on INT system.
Then, on dev system, the second change is made on the same report and locked in the second TR (B) then transported on INT system. It contains change A and change B.

I want to transport first change (A) from INT to QA system, but keep the second change (A + B) to INT system. Does transporting the first TR will only transport the code version of the first change (A) to QA system or the transport of a LIMU REPS object is to basically take a picture of the current version in INT (A + B) and transport it to QA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Released transport contents remain unchanged. When transport requests are released in DEV, they preserve the object version at the release moment, meaning that a transport with change A will exclusively include the object with change A. Subsequently, after importing this transport into QA, only the object with change A will be present in the system.

Answer (score 0):

When you release a transport request, then the system indeed takes a snapshot of the current state of all the objects in the transport and writes them to a file.

When you then import a transport request in a system, that file is read and the objects in the system get overwritten with the contents of the file.

That means when you import the first transport into QA, then the contents of REPS A will be overwritten with the state it had in the DEV system the moment you released the transport request. Should you then import the second transport request as well, then the contents will be overwritten again by the state it had the moment the second transport was released in DEV.